# if number of extreme points of $B_X$ is finite, then $X$ is of finite dimensional?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space. 
Recall that closed unit ball $B_X$ of $X$ is defined by 
$$B_X = \{y\in X: \|y\|\leq 1\}.$$
We say that $x\in X$ is an extreme point of $B_X$ if $x = \frac{1}{2}(u+v)$ where $u,v \in B_X$ implies that $x = u =v.$

> Question: Is it true that if the number of extreme points of $B_X$ is finite, then $X$ is of finite dimensional?

Comment: Krein Milman. ${}{}$

Comment: Krein Milman is for compact convex sets.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Good point. Reflexive thinking on my part...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. The unit ball of the space  $c_0$ of all null sequences does not have any extreme points.